# Getting random numbers to stay the same from function to function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Relatively new to C++ and this has been bugging me for a while.  I'm trying to write a program that will do different things depending on what random number is generated.

To explain what I'm trying to do simply, lets pretend I'm creating a list of athletes and start by randomly generating their heights within a certain range.  Easy to do no problem.  Say then I want to generate their weight, based on their height.  This is where things get messy.  For some reason I can't figure out, the program is randomly generating the weight based on a different height than the one it returns in the first place.  I just don't get it.

Anyway, here is a piece of (very simplified) sample code that hopefully shows what I'm trying to do. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int random(int min, int max, int base)
{
    int random = (rand() % (max - min) + base);

    return random;
}

int height()
{
    int height = random(1, 24, 60);

    return height;
}

int weight()
{
    int weight = height() * 2.77;

    return weight;
}

void main()
{
    srand ((unsigned int)time(0));

    int n = 1;

    while (n <= 10)
        { 
        cout << height() << " and " << weight() << endl;
        ++n;
        }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy. You call `height()` in your `weight()` function. That means you're getting a new random value for the `height`. What you have to do is to modify your `weight()` so that it can pass through a height parameter and calculate the weight based on it (and not on a new random value).

Your new `height()` function would look as follow:

```
int weight(int height)
{
    int weight = height * 2.77;

    return weight;
}
```

In your `main()`:

```
while (n <= 10)
{
    int h = height();
    int w = weight(h);

    cout << h << " and " << w << endl;
    ++n;
}
```

Comment: This one worked like a charm.  Very simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 5):

`weight` is calling `height` *again*, and it will obviously be generating a different number (that's the whole point of an RNG :) ).

To obtain the effect you want you could:

- change `weight` to accept the the `height` as a parameter; then, in the `main`, at each iteration save the value returned by `height` in a temporary variable and pass it to height to obtain the corresponding height;

  ```
  int weight(int height)
  {
      return height*2.77;
  }

  // ... inside the main ...
  while (n <= 10)
  { 
      int curHeight=height();
      cout << curHeight << " and " << weight(curHeight) << endl;
      ++n;
  }
  ```
- move `height` and `weight` to a class, which will store `height` as a private field, adding a `nextPerson` member that will update the internal field to a new random value.

  ```
  class RandomPersonGenerator
  {
      int curHeight;
  public:
      RandomPersonGenerator()
      {
          nextPerson();
      }

      int height() { return curHeight; }
      int weight() { return height()*2.77; }

      void nextPerson()
      {
          curHeight=random(1, 24, 60);
      }
  };

  // ... inside the main ...
  RandomPersonGenerator rpg;
  while (n <= 10)
  { 
      rpg.nextPerson();
      cout << rpg.height() << " and " << rpg.weight() << endl;
      ++n;
  }
  ```

(by the way, it's `int main`, not `void main`, and a `for` cycle is more appropriate than `while` in this situation)

Comment: For some reason that I don't understand your first suggestion didn't work.  It ended up repeating the same pair of numbers ten times instead of giving me ten randoms.  I figure I probably did something wrong there.  As to your second suggestion, you've given me the perfect opening to move into classes, something I need to learn.  So, thanks for that!

Comment: @JeremySharp: did you keep the original `height` function? Can you post your complete code on ideone.com or pastbin.com so I can have a look?

Comment: That may be what I did.  I have to go and redevelop the complete code now...maybe with classes thanks to your suggestion.